# How to remove all non-numeric characters from a MySQL table entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a PHP program to update a MySQL table entry according to a phone number. The phone numbers in the database are entered without limitations and are typically formatted in the XXX-XXX-XXXX way, but sometimes have other characters due to typos. In order to ensure the query works every time, I want to remove all non-numeric characters from the entries so that I can compare the entries to phone numbers formatted like XXXXXXXXXX coming from a separate source.

I've done some research and found some solutions but am unsure how to incorporate them into the PHP script. I am fairly new to MySQL and most of the solutions provided user defined MySQL functions and I don't know how to put them into the PHP script and use them with the query I already have.

Here's one of the solutions I found:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CleanPhoneNumber] (@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9]%'
WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

RETURN @Temp
END
```

And this is the query I need the solution for:

```
$sql = "SELECT pid AS pid FROM patient_data " . 
       "WHERE pid = '$pID' AND phone_cell = '$phone_number';";
```

The query should return the data in the pid column for a single patient, so if the phone number is 1234567890 and the pid is 15, 15 should be returned. I have no output at the moment.

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. A few rows of data can go a long way to help us to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example function definition is Transact-SQL (i.e. for Microsoft SQL Server), it's not valid MySQL syntax.

A function like this doesn't go "into" the PHP code. The function gets created on the MySQL database as a separate step, similar to creating a table.  The PHP code can call (reference) the defined function just like it references builtin functions such as `DATE_FORMAT` or `SUBSTR`.

The SELECT statement follows the pattern of SQL that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Any potentially unsafe values that are incorporated into SQL text must be properly escaped. A better pattern is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

As an example of a MySQL function:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION clean_phone_number(as_phone_string VARCHAR(1024))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
    DECLARE c         CHAR(1)       DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE i         INT DEFAULT   0;
    DECLARE n         INT DEFAULT   0;
    DECLARE ls_digits VARCHAR(20)   DEFAULT '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
    DECLARE ls_retval VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
    IF ( as_phone_string IS NULL OR as_phone_string = '' ) THEN
       RETURN as_phone_string;
    END IF;
    SET n := CHAR_LENGTH(as_phone_string);
    WHILE ( i < n ) DO
       SET i := i + 1;
       SET c := SUBSTR(as_phone_string,i,1);
       IF ( FIND_IN_SET(c,ls_digits) ) THEN
          SET ls_retval := CONCAT(ls_retval,c);
       END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN ls_retval;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

We can execute these statements in the mysql command line client, connected as a user with sufficient privilege, to create the function.

This isn't necessarily the best way to write the function, but it does serve as a demonstration.

Once the function is created, we can reference it a SQL statement, for example:

```
 SELECT t.foo
      , clean_phone_number(t.foo)
   FROM ( SELECT '1' AS foo
          UNION ALL SELECT '1-888-TAXICAB'
          UNION ALL SELECT '888-555-1212'
          UNION ALL SELECT '+=_-()*&^%$#@"''<>?/;:"abc...xyz'
          UNION ALL SELECT ''
          UNION ALL SELECT NULL
        ) t
```